# Is there a way someone can read arrays of bytes which I send with java sockets while using TLS 1.2?

Tags: java, ssl, socket

If anyone can answer me pls I just need an anwer. I know thus isn't maybe right place for this question

I created chatting app with sockets in Java 8 and i use TLS 1.2 My question is: Is there any way that someone can read data i send(read as he can decrypt it)? Maybe something like man in the middle attack or something else.. I should note that the server which i use is just for sending incoming messages to destination clients (not storing anything on it).

I ask this because i was always wondering how come the people who use so called protected apps get caught at the end.What if someone uses my app and start sending some illegal stuff(literally anything). Could this person get caught if there isn't any data storing on my server and am i allowed to claim that my app is definitely secured?

Sorry if it's stupid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS protects the **communication** between client and server **if properly implemented**. This means

- it does not protect against compromising the server or client
- it does not protect against bugs in the application, like XSS, CSRF or similar in web application
- it does not protect against MITM attacks unless the client actually enforces that it gets the expected certificate from the server
- if one of the endpoints of the communication is compromised, then the clear text communication might be intercepted before encryption or after decryption

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: Thing I forgot to mention was I don't send text messages at all. I send files but not whole file. I make that file into multiple arrays and I send them. Is there a way someone can read those byte arrays I send

Comment: @GMdz0ji: It does not matter if this is text or binary content, it is just data. Either the data have additional protection (like the file is encrypted by itself, not only by TLS in transit) or TLS is the only protection they have. "Byte array" is not a protection and splitting a file over multiple transmits is not real protection either - the attacker only needs to attack all these transmits.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reply